# kernel 5.12 can't use find_module

Tags: kernel

When my kernel was upgraded to 5.12, I found that I could not use find_module, so is there any alternative?
ERROR: modpost: "find_module" [/root/sheldon/test.ko] undefined

Comment: It seems they have finally disallowed to search modules in drivers. Probably, they expect that drivers shouldn't do that. In kernel 5.11 it was only a single driver which uses given functionality: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11.22/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_fb_helper.c#L2519. That usage has been eliminated in 5.12.

Comment: thanks for your help. yes ,I found it and I am going to use "__symbol_get" to get the module address to determine whether the module exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I rewrite the new find_insert_module function, which can realize the function of find_module**

```
static struct module *find_insert_module(const char *name)
    {
         struct module *list_mod = NULL;
         /* traverse the module list and find corresponding module*/
         list_for_each_entry(list_mod, THIS_MODULE->list.prev, list)
         {
             if (strcmp(list_mod->name, name) == 0)
             {
                return list_mod;
             }
         }
         printk("[%s] module %s not found\n", THIS_MODULE->name, name);
        //printk("[%s] module %s not found\n", THIS_MODULE->name, name);
         return NULL;
     }
```